# Minimum number of comparision to find the third largest element in an array of distinct integers?

Tags: selection-problem, comparison

For the second largest element, I know that the formula is $n+ \lceil\log n \rceil -2 $

Is there any formula for the third largest element? and if so, what is the derivation?

Comment: For rank $k$ you must perform at least $n-k+\log \binom{n}{k-1}$

Comment: is k-1 the base of log or the combination like nC(k-1) ?

Comment: n over k is a common notation and means binomial expansion of the k-th power in polynomial of order n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem of computing the $k$-th rank element, a lower bound of $n-k+\log \binom{n}{k-1}$ can be proven with decision trees.

For simplicity this proof assumes that the element set $X$ is of size $n$ and its elements are distinct (which makes the problem harder). Moreover, the algorithm may only compare any two elements, and conclude one is either smaller or greater than the other.

---

First, let us claim the following:

> For computing the $k$-th rank element (denoted $x_k$) (using comparisons only), every other element $x_i$ must be involved in a comparison that sets it lesser or greater than the $k$-th rank element.
>
> Formally: for any $x_i$ lesser than $x_k$, $x_i$ must be involved in a comparison of the sort $x_i < x_j \leq x_k$. For any $x_i$ greater than $x_k$, it must be involved in the comparison $x_i > x_j \geq x_k$

The proof by contradiction: Suppose $x$ was not involved in either those comparisons. Then $x$ can be either greater or smaller than $x_k$, which means the $k$-th rank element can change depending on $x$.

---

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a decision tree that finds the $k$-th rank element. We will show $\mathcal{T}$ has at least $2^{n-k} \binom{n}{k-1}$ leaves.

Now, suppose $T_1$ is another decision tree, that *knows* the set of elements greater than $x_k$, denoted by $K_1$. It means $T_1$ does not need to compare any elements of $K_1$, and thus performs $n-k$ comparisons, or has $2^{n-k}$ leaves.

Because of the claim we made earlier, we **know** $\mathcal{T}$ must have performed the comparisons in $T_1$, hence for each leaf in $T_1$ there is a corresponding leaf in $\mathcal{T}$. Moreover, in each of these leaves, the element $x_k$ defines the set $K_1$, which are all the elements greater than $x_k$.

How many trees like $T_1$ are there? As many as the different choices you can make for the set $K_1$, which is selecting $k-1$ elements out of $n$, which is exactly $\binom{n}{k-1}$. And for each of these trees, there are at least $2^{n-k}$ leaves in $\mathcal{T}$, which are essentially distinct, since they define distinct sets $K_i$.

It follows that $\mathcal{T}$ has at least $2^{n-k} \binom{n}{k-1}$ leaves, therefore the lower bound is $\log$ of the same:

$$n-k+\log \binom{n}{k-1}$$